# Are Kanban cadences and Kanban Feedback Loops are the same thing?

Tags: kanban, feedback

I have encountered two sources which contradict each other it terms of definitions and relations between Kanban cadences and Kanban Feedback Loops.

One seems to be saying they are different things.
https://kanbanize.com/kanban-resources/getting-started/kanban-encyclopedia/

Another seems to present them as the same thing.
https://aktiasolutions.com/kanban-cadences-kanban-feedback-loops/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst feedback is vital, they are not the same thing.

A cadence is a regular rhythm of activity. For example, in Scrum, most ceremonies have a once-per-sprint cadence. I'm guessing they use the term "cadence" instead of frequency because they want to remove the time-based association of frequency and instead allow for more event-based occurrence. For example, you might choose to review each feature instead of all features at the end of each sprint if you're taking more of a Kanban approach.

Cadence describes the regularity in which you do certain activities. Those activities may be important in the feedback process, but the cadence itself is not the feedback loop.

The references you provide are about the "The Seven Kanban Cadences", those seven items are actually meetings and the feedback loops are the relationships between those meetings or candences.